# How to plot histogram and give name to categorial data using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

This is the head of my dataset:

```
    ï..age sex cp trestbps chol fbs restecg thalach exang oldpeak slope ca thal
1     63   1  3      145  233   1       0     150     0     2.3     0  0    1
2     37   1  2      130  250   0       1     187     0     3.5     0  0    2
3     41   0  1      130  204   0       0     172     0     1.4     2  0    2
4     56   1  1      120  236   0       1     178     0     0.8     2  0    2
5     57   0  0      120  354   0       1     163     1     0.6     2  0    2
6     57   1  0      140  192   0       1     148     0     0.4     1  0    1
  target
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
5      1
6      1
```

I want to plot an histogram based on dependent variable(target) only with the categoral data and chage the value og this data by giving it is names
I tried this code but not working and give me this error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `thal`. x object 'thal' not found
> i Input `thal` is `recode_factor(thal,` 3`= "normal",`6`= "fixed defect",`7 `= "reversible defect")`. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see
> where the error occurred. In addition: Warning messages: 1: Ignoring
> unknown aesthetics: fill  2: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill  3:
> Problem with `mutate()` input `cp`. i Unreplaced values treated as NA
> as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or
> supply .default i Input `cp` is `recode_factor(...)`.  4: Unreplaced
> values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify
> replacements exhaustively or supply .default  5: Problem with
> `mutate()` input `slope`. i Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is
> not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply
> .default i Input `slope` is `recode_factor(slope,` 1`= "up-sloaping",`2`= "flat",`3 `= "down-sloaping")`.  6: Unreplaced values treated
> as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements
> exhaustively or supply .default

and this is my code:

```
categorial.df<-df %>% select(2,3,5,6,7,9,11,14)

#Select categorical vars, recode them to their character values, convert to long format
hd_long_fact_tbl <- categorial.df  %>%
  select(1:8) %>%
  mutate(sex = recode_factor(sex, `0` = "female", 
                             `1` = "male" ),
         cp = recode_factor(cp, `1` = "typical",   
                                         `2` = "atypical",
                                         `3` = "non-angina", 
                                         `4` = "asymptomatic"),
         fbs = recode_factor(fbs, `0` = "<= 120 mg/dl", 
                                             `1` = "> 120 mg/dl"),
         restecg = recode_factor(restecg, `0` = "normal",
                                     `1` = "ST-T abnormality",
                                     `2` = "LV hypertrophy"),
         exang = recode_factor(exang, `0` = "no",
                                                 `1` = "yes"),
         slope = recode_factor(slope, `1` = "up-sloaping",
                                                  `2` = "flat",
                                                  `3` = "down-sloaping"),
         thal = recode_factor(thal, `3` = "normal",
                                     `6` = "fixed defect",
                                     `7` = "reversible defect")) %>%
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", -target)
#Visualize with bar plot
hd_long_fact_tbl %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(x        = value, 
               fill     = target), 
           alpha    = .6, 
           position = "dodge", 
           color    = "black",
           width    = .8
  ) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "",
       title = "Scaled Effect of Categorical Variables") +
  theme(axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free", nrow = 4) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#fde725ff", "#20a486ff"),
    name   = "Heart\nDisease",
    labels = c("No HD", "Yes HD"))
plot(hd_long_cont_tbl)
```

Comment: Main issue is that you missed to select your variable `thal`. Try with `categorial.df<-df %>% select(2,3,5,6,7,9,11,13, 14)` and `categorial.df  %>%
  select(1:9)` or remove `select(1:8)` all together. The reason for the other warnings is that you have not specified recodings for all values present in your dataset. e.g. there is a value `0` in cp but no lable given in `recode_factor`